# how to find the path of a specific file

Tags: python, filesystems

I want to find the full path to a file/folder by it's name only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is `in` your working `dir`:

Using `os`:

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath("image.png"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
C:\Users\dirtybit\PycharmProjects\opencv-basics\image.png
```

**EDIT**:

Let's say you have no idea where it is:

```
import os

dirs = ['c:\\','d:\\']     # your desired dirs to search under
for dir in dirs:
    for r,d,f in os.walk(dir):
        for files in f:
             if files == "db.jpg":
                  print(os.path.join(r,files))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
 C:\Users\dirtybit\PycharmProjects\opencv-basics\image.png
```

**EDIT 2**:

If you only want to check in a specific `dir`:

```
for r,d,f in os.walk('d:\\'):
    for files in f:
        if files == "db.jpg":
            print(os.path.join(r,files))
```

Comment: by using that code I'm only getting the path to the place I'm running the code from Is there any other way

Comment: thank you very much it helped me a lot, I have one last question can I found with that specific dir?

Comment: @שחראימלפרב Kindly check the edit 3. PS. If this answer helped you may accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers!

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I want to search for the specific dir

Comment: @שחראימלפרב  sure you should look for the `d` in that case, I recommend reading: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk